# TFS: Change state category

Tags: tfs

I added a new state to my TFS-Template `Ready for Shipping`.

The Transitions are working fine, but I my new state acts like the `Removed`-State. So I think my new State has the wrong State-Category.

**How can I change the State-Category of my new state?**

I saw this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/06/18/states-customization-on-team-services/), but I dont find my process template there. And it should only change the template for a specific project. I think its not for TFS too.

Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of categories is in a file called `categories.xml` (for each team project).

The syntax is:

```
<CATEGORIES>  
      <CATEGORY name="category display name" refname="category reference name">  
      <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="work item type reference name" />  
      <WORKITEMTYPE name="work item type reference name" />  
      </CATEGORY>  
</CATEGORIES>
```

You need to export the file with this command:

```
witadmin exportcategories /collection:CollectionURL /p:Project
[/f:FileName] [/e:Encoding]
```

Edit the file and add the new state to the correct category.

Import the file with this command:

```
witadmin importcategories /collection:CollectionURL /p:Project /f:FileName [/e:Encoding]
```

More information you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/xml/categories-xml-element-reference?view=vsts) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-categories?view=tfs-2018).